# Finding max memory usage of the function in python using psutil differ when testing with the aws lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, memory-management

Calculated the memory usage of the function in python using this:

```
process = psutil.Process()
start_memory = process.memory_info().rss
print(f"Memory Usage : {end_memory} bytes")
```

This gives output as: Memory Usage: 22220800 bytes

But when I tried to find the max memory used for the same function in AWS lambda function it shows:

Max Memory Used: 36 MB

Nearly 14MB is the difference. Why?

Comment: I believe psutil is used to get the memory usage of the running processes. So, when your lambda runs another program calls it which is the AWS function caller. So the psutil calculate the memory usage for your lambda and your lambda caller. i hope it make sense.

Comment: I trace the memory usage for this sample code:                                                                            def main():
    a = 20 * 1000
    b = a * 100
    c = b * 100
    print(c)
    print("Main process completed")                                                                                                      For this function the memory usage differ when tested it with psutil and in aws lambda